# Integrating MapBasic with .NET Problem with TextBox Controls

Tags: c#, .net, map-basic

I'm trying to integrate Map-Basic with .NET
The final goal is to get an app capable to set address numbers to segment in a friendly and automated way
The problem I having is that TextBoxes in the .NET form are not responsive at all. They don't even get the initial value.
Here is a simplified example code.

Form1.Designer.cs

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 67);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 26);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.textBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.textBox1.Text = "Initial text";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 184);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 56);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private Button button1;
}
```

This is Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click");
    }
}
```

And finally a class with static method

```
public class InterfaceClass
{
    static Form1 form;
    public static void showMainWindow(int hwnd)
    {
        form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
        form.PerformLayout();
    }
}
```

My MB (MapBasic) File looks like this. (Having removed some sub declares. It compiles successfully)

Include "mapbasic.def"

Declare Method showMainWindow Class "SetNumberLib.InterfaceClass" Lib "SetNumberLib.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer)

Sub Main

```
Create Menu "Map Numbering" As
    "Show Window" Calling ShowWindow,
    "Exit" Calling EndApp
Alter Menu bar Add "Map Numbering"
```

End Sub

Sub ShowWindow

```
Dim hwndPro As Integer
hwndPro = SystemInfo(SYS_INFO_MAPINFOWND)
Call showMainWindow(hwndPro)
```

End Sub

Back to the form. The Button works fine. The messagebox is shown when clicked
The textbox is like a non reactive picture. Worse. I doubt it gets the redraw.
Any idea?
Am I missing something.
By the way. When I test the dll from a Net App the text-boxes work fine.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

New Info:
RichTextBOx Works fine. The problem is still with TextBoxes.
Any Clue?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that this miss behaviour stooped the next day when I restarted Mapinfo.
The real solution is beyond my hands but a fresh Mapinfo instance works fine integrated with .NET.